# HTML5 Recording audio with low kbps

Tags: javascript, html, audio-recording, web-audio-api

I did a audio recorder using the getUserMedia(). And saving the file using the Recorder.js

But the output file is far heavier than I'd like it was.

A 4 minutes audio record have something like 40mb. And i can't send it to my server. If so,it will crash.

So, I searched how to reduce the recording kbps. But I found nothing. Just some Flash solutions. But these don't fit to my project.

So, my question is, is possible to reduce the kbps of a audio record using the getUserMedia() ?

Answer (score 11):

In my case Chrome records audio at 96kHz and Firefox at 44.1kHz, that makes huge *WAV* files. I implemented a downsampling function inside recorderWorker.js where you can select the sample ratio you want, like 16000.

```js
function downsampleBuffer(buffer, rate) {
    if (rate == sampleRate) {
        return buffer;
    }
    if (rate > sampleRate) {
        throw "downsampling rate show be smaller than original sample rate";
    }
    var sampleRateRatio = sampleRate / rate;
    var newLength = Math.round(buffer.length / sampleRateRatio);
    var result = new Float32Array(newLength);
    var offsetResult = 0;
    var offsetBuffer = 0;
    while (offsetResult < result.length) {
        var nextOffsetBuffer = Math.round((offsetResult + 1) * sampleRateRatio);
        var accum = 0, count = 0;
        for (var i = offsetBuffer; i < nextOffsetBuffer && i < buffer.length; i++) {
            accum += buffer[i];
            count++;
        }
        result[offsetResult] = accum / count;
        offsetResult++;
        offsetBuffer = nextOffsetBuffer;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and i call it when exporting the wav file:

```js
function exportWAV(rate, type) {
    var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength);
    var bufferR = mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength);
    var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
    var downsampledBuffer = downsampleBuffer(interleaved, rate);
    var dataview = encodeWAV(rate, downsampledBuffer, false);
    var audioBlob = new Blob([ dataview ], {
        type : type
    });

    this.postMessage(audioBlob);
}
```

Comment: Nice! I'll test it as soon as possible!

Comment: another strategy could be not to calculate the average bitrate and only consider one sample per step: `result[offsetResult] = buffer[offsetBuffer];`

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple options.

First, for smaller size reductions, you can always modify the recorderWorker.js file in RecorderJS to use a lower sample rate and bit depth. This would require a bit of knowledge of how digital audio works, and some level of comfort working with typed arrays - but shouldn't be too hard. If you go down that road, [this page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) has a decent explanation of the WAVE format. Reducing bit depth should be fairly straight-forward. Downsampling can be a little more complex, but should still be pretty doable with a little bit of research. Once you've got the bit depth and sample rate you want, changing the header in RecorderJS's `encodeWAV` function should be pretty trivial.

The other option would be to convert to a lossy format (e.g. MP3). [This](https://github.com/akrennmair/libmp3lame-js) is the only library I know of right now that will do that, although there may be more. I haven't actually used this, and have heard it's a bit slow - but you can probably run it in a web worker if it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way to downsample in recorderWorker.js is explained pretty well in this question from April/May: [Decrease bitrate on WAV file created with recorderjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296645/decrease-bitrate-on-wav-file-created-with-recorderjs).