# Register Wav file at 16000Hz sample rate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wav, audio-recording

I am trying to use [angular-recorder](https://github.com/logbon72/angular-recorder) to record a wav file:

- the microphone is at 16000Hz sample rate
- the default sample rate is 44100Hz.

Changing the sample rate from 41000 to 16000 did not make it work.

I tried the `downsampleBuffer` function from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296645/decrease-bitrate-on-wav-file-created-with-recorderjs) but it just makes the wav file play more quickly.

Comment: It may help to provide some samples of the code you are using so far

Comment: [This is](https://github.com/logbon72/angular-recorder/blob/master/src/html5-recorder.js) the code that create the wave