# Need desired format of .wav In Recoder.js

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, downsampling, recorder.js

I am using recorder.js to record audio. When I download .wav file it is 48KHz but I want in 16KHz, mono channel.

```
function init(config) {
            sampleRate = config.sampleRate; //to 16000
            numChannels = config.numChannels; //to 1
            initBuffers();
        }
```

It changes the recorded voice (like a voice of the robot).

Help me to get a voice in 16KHz, mono .wav file in a normal voice. (Thanx in Advance)

[My Code Is Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oMPrSaEK2s2jpIjqc1wVNMByoGjInukv)

Comment: I have followed this forum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296645/decrease-bitrate-on-wav-file-created-with-recorderjsAnd then I am able to get my desired result.

Comment: You can get Recorder.js with downsampling here: https://gitlab.com/haideralishafqat/WebAudioRecorder.git

Comment: I tried your code. When I downloaded the wav files the sample rate has gone down to 16000 but the audio file length is 0 therefore cannot play it back.